AWS Custom Audit Logging
Our stack is in AWS. As part of an integration with a third party I'm required to keep track of some aspects of requests made to their API for potential future auditing.
In the past, we've rolled our own solution for this with S3 buckets with legal hold enabled, but that required writing and testing code, and seemed heavy-handed.
CloudTrail seemed like a good solution - insert the required details into a DynamoDB table, and have a CloudTrail Event Data Store track the table's stream. However this seems finicky to set up and you're only allowed 10 Event Data Stores per account which is a significant limitation for automated testing - especially when they can't be deleted without waiting for seven days.
I've also briefly looked at AuditManager, but it seems overkill for what we need.
Is there another AWS service that can help with this that I've missed, or do I need to keep using something custom?
